# Collision with other @Primary-annotated bean (NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException)

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a bean:

```
@Bean("imageKitPath")
public String imageKitPath() {
    return "/main";
}
```

However, in tests I want this bean to have `/test` value. I successfully implemented it like this:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public String imageKitPath2() {
    return "/test";
}
```

Now, here's the issue. I have also successfully implemented JWT-based authentication. However, I would like to have different signature for tests and for production.

In my production code, I have a bean with JWT's signature:

```
@Bean("jwtKey")
public String jwtKey() {
    // some logic to read key from file
    return jwtKey;
}
```

And, similarly to previous example, in tests it looks like this:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public String jwtKey2() {
    // some logic to read key from application.properties
    return jwtKey;
}
```

Both beans are created correctly and have values I expect them to have. The issue lies in injecting these values to other components. For example, in my `JwtService` class (which is `@Service`-annotated), I struggle to autowire them. I've tried multiple solutions.

1.

```
private final String jwtKey;

@Autowired
public JwtService(String jwtKey) {
    this.jwtKey = jwtKey;
}
```

This will work just fine in production where there's no second bean (`jwtKey2`). But, the tests will fail to load context with `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: more than one 'primary' bean found among candidates`.

2.

```
private final String jwtKey;

@Autowired
public JwtService(@Qualifier("jwtKey") String jwtKey) {
    this.jwtKey = jwtKey;
}
```

Again, works in production, but in tests it will use the production's value of JWT, not the one I've specified in tests.

3.

```
private final String jwtKey;

@Autowired
public JwtService(@Qualifier("jwtKey2") String jwtKey) {
    this.jwtKey = jwtKey;
}
```

And this one works correctly in tests, but - obviously - will fail in production as there's no `jwtKey2` bean.

The reason that I've described `imageKitPath` bean is simple. Because tests specify a bean that overrides `imageKitPath` by using `@Primary`, Spring - I think - can not differentiate between `imageKitPath2` and `jwtKey2`. Removing `imageKitPath` beans entirely solves the JWT's bean issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve looks like a perfect use-case for properties. So your Provider Bean would look like this:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "imageKit")
public class ConfigProperties {
    
    private String path;

    // getters, setters

}
```

application.properties:

```
imageKit.path="/main"
```

The field `path` here would map to `imageKit.path` in your `application.properties`.  For testing, you can provide a different `application.properties` file in your `test` folder, dynamically replacing the provided value. If you need more values in parallel, consider using profiles.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes, that's what I also have been thinking about. I've still remained curious for the problem I've encountered, thus created the post. I'll be trying to implement these bean values right now as it also seems, like you said, a perfect use-case for them.

Comment: I've managed to set both JWT key in `jwt.properties` file and `imageKit.path` in `application.properties`. Values for tests and production code differ and there's no problem with loading the context anymore in neither of environments. I've also realized how making these two beans properties simplified the code. Thank you.

Comment: If you have multiple beans of the same type, spring does not now which one to inject. There are several ways of resolving that. One would be to use `@Primary` which defines a default bean if no other criteria are given. `@Qualifier` works to select one by a "query". However, a bean does one thing (in your case provide a string), so having multiple beans fulfilling the same task is not intended, that's why you hit that wall :).

Comment: Yes. `@Primary` did the job, when there was only one String bean annotated with it. Obviously, I've grown suspicious of the String type, so I even started creating enums for both beans, but found your solution much simpler. Retrospectively I can see that I did everything to dodge the `.properties`. And I don't quite know why as I use properties in my current project relatively extensively.